# My input is being consumed

Tags: c, scanf

Here I have an infinite do-while loop that asks for an input, when I type in 1,2,3, and 4, it works fine, and when I type in any other number, that works fine too.

But when I type in a letter or a special character, it will go through the code as expected and show the "Try again" message. But it won't allow me to enter anything after that, either the code is clearing and displaying constantly or it's just frozen. Either way, I need to be able to fix this.

```
do
 {
    system("cls");

    printf("What would you like to do?");
    printf("\n1.View the databases");
    printf("\n2.Add data");
    printf("\n3.Create new user");
    printf("\n\n\n4.Exit");
    printf("\n\n\n");
    scanf("\n%d",&Choice);

    if(Choice == 1 ) //Selection
    {
         system("color 0c"); //Function's are color coded
         View();
    }
    else if(Choice == 2)
    {
         system("color 0e");
         Edit();
    }
    else if(Choice == 3)
    {
         system("color 0a");
         Append();
    }
    else if(Choice == 4)
    {
         exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
         printf("Try again");
         getch();
     }
}
while(1==1);//Infinite loop
}
```

Input: "a" , Expected output: Try again.. (Asks for input once again). Actual output: Try again (Cannot eneter input)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should really check the return value of `scanf()` for successful completion. Check the man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf).

Otherwise, even if `scanf()` fails, you condition check(s) will keep on executing, possibly with wrong value in `Choice`.

Note: If the very first time `scanf()` fails, you'll be encountering a `read-before-write` secnario [if `choice` is not initialized, though], which may very well lead to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: I'm guessing a Case: Function would give the same result also?

Answer (score 0):

try instead of this

```
scanf("\n%d",&Choice);
```

this:

```
scanf("%d",&Choice);
printf("\n");
```

I know it seems pretty rudimentary but I ve had this problem myself and sometimes scanf can be buggy or act really strange.Just give it a try